# Django: ImportError "doesn't look like a module path

Tags: python, django

I just started to learn Django and I tried to add a middleware to my application.

Under ProjectFolder/app I have the following files:

1. an empty `__init__.py` file
2. settings.py file - the content of this file is default except for:

```
  MIDDLEWARE = (
     'SimpleMiddleware',
     'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
     'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
     'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
     'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
     'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
     'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
     'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
 )
```

3. SimpleMiddleware.py file:

```
class SimpleMiddleware(MiddlewareMixin):

    def __init__(self, get_response):
        print("***********************************SIMPLE MIDDLEWARE")
        self.get_response = get_response
        # One-time configuration and initialization.

    def __call__(self, request):
        # Code to be executed for each request before
        # the view (and later middleware) are called.
        print("***********************************SIMPLE MIDDLEWARE")
        response = self.get_response(request)
        # Code to be executed for each request/response after
        # the view is called.
        return response

    def process_request(self, request):
        print("***********************************SIMPLE MIDDLEWARE")
        return None
```

4. url.py file:

```
    from app import views

    urlpatterns = [
        path('hello', views.index, name='index'),
        path('core', include('core.urls')),
    ]
```

However, when I run the application by the command "python manage.py runserver", I get the error:

> ImportError: SimpleMiddleware doesn't look like a module path

Do you know what I'm doing wrong?

If you want to see the complete code, please click here:
https://bitbucket.org/MATAN_BL/djangotry/src/master/app/

Comment: You must put the class name in your `MIDDLEWARE` list. Try `SimpleMiddleware.SimpleMiddleware`. Also it's a good idea to create your project using `django-admin startproject` and stick to the default directory structure when you first start learning Django.

Comment: I tried it. I got ImportError: No module named 'SimpleMiddleware'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need the full path to your middleware, assuming the structure you've given that'd likely be `app.SimpleMiddleware.SimpleMiddleware`

```
MIDDLEWARE = (
     'app.SimpleMiddleware.SimpleMiddleware',
     'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
     'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
     'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
     'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
     'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
     'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
     'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
 )
```